# JQuery: setting focus on an input field on a specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set focus on Customer Name only on the search_orders.php page. The code below is supposed to put the cursor in the Name input if on the order search page. Somehow this doesn't work. Please suggest any change to my code that will fix this. Attached is the UI for searching orders, where I need the focus set on Customer Name.

[image]

```
function po_number_first(){
   if (document.location.href.indexOf("search_orders")==-1){
      document.search_form.po_number.focus();
}else{
     document.getElementById("Name").focus();
}
}
```

The function call is in a smartyTemplate files as seen in the code below.

```
{include file="header.tpl" page_name=Search extra_javascript='<script language="JavaScript" src="includes/search_orders.js"></script>' on_load_script='po_number_first()'}
```

Comment: Well is there an error in the console?

Comment: Console doesn't show anything.

Comment: Did you debug and see if your code is called?

Comment: Yes, it is being called. I now see that the focus isn't set on po_number search field on non order search page.

Comment: Do you realize that code says if the page is not search_orders focus po_number

Comment: Yes, focusing po_number on other pages doesn't seem to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding it inside a function please try:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   if ( window.location.href.indexOf('/search_orders') > -1 ) {
     jQuery( "#target" ).focus();
   }else{
     jQuery( "#Name" ).focus();
   }
});
```

Comment: Tried this, but didn't help. Could you please suggest another solution if there is any?

Comment: Great! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Set unique id for **Customer Name** input field **element**.

   `<input id="customerNameId">`
2. Now in `<script></script>` tag for that page, write following snippet

```js
   window.onload = () => document.getElementById("customerNameId").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your element is loaded, rendered. Secondly, you need to make sure that there's no code that's assigning focus to a different element instead of yours.

**Regarding waiting for loading and rendering element:**

As mentioned in other answers you need to wait for you page to load first. If it didn't work, then I'd suggest that you make sure that you don't have an iframe as parent element of that target input. If you do, you need to find a way to do that inside an iframe. That might be a tricky task to do and most likely it's going to take decent time if you try to get inside an iframe from outside of a parent page. But overall its doable.

Also is this target input present in the page code that is loaded? Or is it generated by js after page is loaded. If it's loaded later, then you might need to wrap your code into `$(document).ready` first and then also wrap it into `$('customer-name-input-selector').ready` to make sure your element exists already to do something with it afterwards. You might also need to do the same with some elements in a html tree between document and your target element to wait for elements to appear in steps. Still not the best way to handle it though.

If you're using some sort of js library that's generating the whole thing, then the easiest and best solution would be to find a way to get inside of that library and use its tools to get access to your target element.

**Regarding focus given to other element:**

For that you need to investigate your code and pay attention to where your focus initially is, when you open that page.

**Bottom line:**
I'm not posting examples firstly, because of NDA, secondly, because it might differ from case to case.
Once when I stumbled upon a js library with iframe and generated form inside by js from scratch, I've been doing access from parent page into an iframe, then I was messing with elements inside, but it didn't work properly evantually in that particular case and I've ended up reporting it to library developers and over time they've added functionality that allowed me to customize whatever I needed.

In other cases usually just waiting for page to load and then for element to appear on the page (couple of `ready` events) does the trick.